# How to simplify nested select in where clause?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have 4 tables `EMPLOYEE`, `COMPANY`, `WORKS` and `MANAGES`. The tables are defined as follows-

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    STREET VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    CITY VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE COMPANY
(
    COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CITY VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE WORKS
(
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_NAME),
    COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL REFERENCES COMPANY(COMPANY_NAME),
    SALARY NUMBER(12,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MANAGES
(
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_NAME),
    MANAGER_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I need to find all the employees who live in the same city as the company for which they work. So far I have done this.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS Names
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE CITY = (
    SELECT CITY
    FROM COMPANY
    WHERE COMPANY_NAME = (
        SELECT COMPANY_NAME
        FROM WORKS
        WHERE WORKS.EMPLOYEE_NAME = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME
    )
);
```

It's working fine. But I want to know is there any simpler way to do this query?

Comment: Learn what an INNER JOIN is, and you'll reduce it to about a single line of SQL. You should also rethink your columns. What happens if you have two employees named 'John Smith' or a company that has two offices in the same city?

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your suggestion. I think i should change the primary key.

Comment: I think you should add ID columns to EMPLOYEE and COMPANY, and then your WORKS table would be EMPLOYEE_ID, COMPANY_ID, and your MANAGES table would become EMPLOYEE_ID, MANAGER_ID, where manager_id is an EMPLOYEE_ID (a worker can't be managed by a non-employee, right?).

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, you are right. Every manager is an employee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an explicit inner join instead of nested  subselect

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS Names
FROM EMPLOYEE
INNER JOIN WORKS ON  WORKS.EMPLOYEE_NAME = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME
INNER JOIN COMPANY ON  EMPLOYEE.CITY = COMPANY.CITY
```

Comment: It gives an error - `00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"`

Comment: Answer  updated  with explict table name for employee

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar   .just a suggestion .. related  to your question are posted  several right  answer .. you should choose one of these and mark it as accepted ..

Comment: I accepted your answer. It's the simplest one. But, when i'm writing the query, `EMPLOYEE` is underlined and shows `EMPLOYEE is disconnected from the rest of the join graph`, though the statement is running and working well. Can you tell me why it's underlined ??

Comment: which ide you are using ..  ?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME As Names
FROM EMPLOYEE
INNER JOIN WORKS ON WORKS.EMPLOYEE_NAME = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME
INNER JOIN COMPANY ON COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME = WORKS.COMPANY_NAME
WHERE COMPANY.CITY = EMPLOYEE.CITY
```

This is essentially what Ken White was suggesting using the inner join.

Comment: Can you explain please why `SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME` gives error - `"column ambiguously defined"` but `SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME` works well ??

Comment: EMPLOYEE_NAME exists in two tables, EMPLOYEE and WORKS, so when you just say you want the EMPLOYEE_NAME field, SQL doesn't know which table you want to get the data from. That's why it's ambiguous. So you just need to specify the table name and field name in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 4):

You mention a `WHERE` clause so you could do:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_NAME As Names
FROM EMPLOYEE e
WHERE e.CITY = (SELECT c.CITY
                FROM Company c JOIN
                     Works w
                     ON c.COMPANY_NAME = w.COMPANY_NAME
                WHERE w.EMPLOYEE_NAME = e.EMPLOYEE_NAME
               );
```

Notes:

- This assumes that employees only work for one company.  Otherwise, the subquery could return multiple rows.  You can handle this situation by changing the `=` to `IN`.
- Names are a really bad key to use for foreign key relationships.  Usually numeric ids are better.  What happens if an employee or company changes names?
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. But i want to know one thing. Below Sid gave an answer selecting columns from multiple tables and checking the conditions in where clause. That looks simpler. So, is there any advantage  of using INNER JOIN or both just fine ?

Comment: Sid's answer uses archaic syntax for joins that has been out-of-date for about 2 decades.  The proper way to write a `JOIN` in SQL is with the explicit `JOIN` syntax and an `ON` clause.  If you want to use that approach, then user3498540's solution is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select employee.employee_name 

    from company, employee, works 

    where company.company_name=works.company_name 

      and works.employee_name=employee.employee_name 
      and employee.city = company.city
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.